# I want to know how Magento save order when return after successful payment in paypal_express

Tags: magento, paypal

Here is a condition in my latest project where I have to create order after successful payment done through Paypal Express programatically.

When I do it through Magento normal flow it is working very fine, but I want to do it programatically myself.

I tried this but it gives error that payment method is not available.

```
$quote->collectTotals();
$service = Mage::getModel("sales/service_quote", $quote);
$service->submitAll();
$order = $service->getOrder();
if($order) {
    Mage::dispatchEvent("checkout_type_onepage_save_order_after", array("order" => $order, "quote" => $quote));
    try {
        $order->sendNewOrderEmail();
    }
    catch(Exception $e) {
        Mage::logException($e);
    }
}
```

I tried this also but nothing works

```
$quote = Mage::getModel("sales/quote")->setStore(Mage::getSingleton("core/store")->load(1))->load($shoppingCartId);
$checkout = Mage::getSingleton('paypal/express_checkout', array(
    'config' => Mage::getModel('paypal/config', array(Mage_Paypal_Model_Config::METHOD_WPP_EXPRESS)),
    'quote'  => $quote,
));
$detailsBlock = new Mage_Paypal_Block_Express_Review_Details();
$detailsBlock->setQuote($quote);
$checkout->updateShippingMethod("ups_GND");
$session->setLastQuoteId($shoppingCartId)->setLastSuccessQuoteId($shoppingCartId);
$order = $checkout->getOrder();
if ($order){
    $session->setLastOrderId($order->getId())->setLastRealOrderId($order->getIncrementId());
    echo "<br>".$order->getData();
}
```

Any help is much appreciated.  :)

Comment: I want to do it programatically myself <- I somehow doubt that because your question shows no research or attempts.

Comment: @timgeb please check my edits, i tried it already but nothing works.

Comment: fair enough, close vote retracted